# Can DUET be run on a computer already has UEFI?

Tags: uefi, clover, chameleon, opencore

Can DUET and programs based on it—such as OpenCore and Clover—be run on a UEFI-only computer? For instance, let's say that a particular PC has UEFI but not secure boot and they wish to test out secure boot (the secure data is usually stored in a file in the case of DUET on BIOS). Can DUET, Clover, or OpenCore provide emulation of this?